# pandas bring data from one df to another issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set that has a count of duplicates:

```py
#Count number of injuries by levels for each players
levelcount = df.groupby(['Relinquished','Severity']).size().reset_index(name='count')
levelcount['DTD'] = ''
levelcount['DNP'] = ''
levelcount['out indefinitely'] = ''
levelcount['ou t for season'] = ''
levelcount.head(4)

   Relinquished  Severity Count DTD DNP outindefinitely outforseason
0   player1         1       1
1   player1         3       1
2   player2         3       1
3   player3         1       3
```

I want to add the count values to a different dataframe with an appropriate order:
  1:DTD,
  2:DNP,
  3:out for indefinitely,
  4: out for the season.

I tried using if statements but I can't seem the make a breakthrough. Thank you in advance!

```
if levelcount['Severity'] == 1:
    df_extension['DTD'] = levelcount[''] 
if levelcount['Severity'] == 2:
    df_extension['DNP'] = levelcount[''] 
if levelcount['Severity'] == 3:
    df_extension['out indefinitely'] = levelcount[''] 
if levelcount['Severity'] == 4:
    df_extension['out for season'] = levelcount['']
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu9s2.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: can you please share share a sample of dataframe ?

Comment: I updated what the dataframe looks like on the post!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary for new column, append to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
levelcount = df.groupby(['Relinquished','Severity']).size().reset_index(name='count')
d = {1:'DTD',2:'DNP',3:'outindefinitely',4:'outforseason'}

new = levelcount.set_index(levelcount['Severity'].map(d), append=True)['Count'].unstack()
levelcount = levelcount.join(new.reindex(list(d.values()), axis=1))
print (levelcount)
  Relinquished  Severity  Count  DTD  DNP  outindefinitely  outforseason
0      player1         1      1  1.0  NaN              NaN           NaN
1      player1         3      1  NaN  NaN              1.0           NaN
2      player2         3      1  NaN  NaN              1.0           NaN
3      player3         1      3  3.0  NaN              NaN           NaN
```

Your solution is possible by loop by dictionary and set new columns:

```
levelcount = df.groupby(['Relinquished','Severity']).size().reset_index(name='count')
d = {1:'DTD',2:'DNP',3:'outindefinitely',4:'outforseason'}

for k, v in d.items():
    levecount = levelcount.loc[levelcount['Severity'] == k, v] = levelcount['count']
```

Comment: I was able to do this using levecount = levelcount.loc[levelcount['Severity'] == 1, 'DTD'] = levelcount['count']

Comment: @AlYoo - OK, if use this solution then remove `levelcount['DTD'] = ''
levelcount['DNP'] = ''
levelcount['out indefinitely'] = ''
levelcount['ou t for season'] = ''`

Comment: @AlYoo - Added your modified solution.