# pandas collapsing row data

Tags: python, pandas

New to pandas, I m climbing my learning curve here.
I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
Relinquished Degree Count DTD DNP outindefinitely seasonout 
-----------------------------------------------------------
player1        1      1    1    
player1        3      1                1
```

Values in column Degree ranges from 1 to 4 and it represents degree of injury (DTD,DNP,outindefinitely,seasonout).
How do I merge the two rows that has same player name under column Relinquished?
Expected output:

```
Relinquished DTD DNP outindefinitely seasonout 
-----------------------------------------------------------
player1        1        1
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot [replace missing values to empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61201110/2901002) in first step and then aggregate `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby('Relinquished').sum()
```

If want specify columns for sum:

```
print (df)
  Relinquished  Degree  Count  DTD  DNP  outindefinitely  seasonout
0      player1       1      1  1.0  NaN              NaN        NaN
1      player1       3      1  NaN  NaN              1.0        NaN

df = df.groupby('Relinquished')['DTD','DNP','outindefinitely','seasonout'].sum()
print (df)
              DTD  DNP  outindefinitely  seasonout
Relinquished                                      
player1       1.0  0.0              1.0        0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('Relinquished').sum()
```

Comment: This returns sum of the count which is not a behaviour I was looking for

Comment: just select column `['DTD','DNP','outindefinitely','seasonout' ]`

Comment: I selected the columns but it only returns value for season out